# How to use db transcation for an OleDb token places in a loop?

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, oledbcommand

There comes an interesting problem for you, it seems very easy in code:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(……))
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(con);
    OleDbTranscation trans = con.BeginTranscation();
    cmd.CommandText = "update xxx set field1=@field1,field2=@field2 where field3=@field3";

    //Suppose "pCollection" is a collection variable defined before, and this is a stack type.

   Point p = pCollection.Pop();

   while(pCollection.Count!=0)
   {
      cmd.Parameters["@field1"].Value = p.Field1;
      cmd.Parameters["@field2"].Value = p.Field2;
      cmd.Parameters["@field3"].Value = p.Field3;
      cmd.Parameters["@field4"].Value = p.Field4;
      p = pCollection.Pop();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   trans.Commit();
}
```

The codes above seems roughly right, however if you run it and you will find that only the last record is updated, because the parameters of SqlCommand are overridden by the latter time of loop, and all the previous loop's parameters are referring to the same parameters of SqlCommand, so only the last time the parameters' values take action. And all the transcations are pointing to the last time of updating record.So my question is **How to make each updating statement takes action within the whole transcation (each updating SQL has different values of parameters)?**

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe give us the code without syntax errors?

Comment: I think you meant to have your command enlisted within the transaction you've created. Try the OleDbCommand constructor overload that also takes a transaction.

Comment: @Biscuits: Thanks. However I'm afraid that doesn't help. You've only changed the order of Transcation but you didn't solve the problem that the Parameters will be overridden. So the result is that only the last record is updated.

Comment: Did you try creating separate instances of OleDbCommand every time within the while-loop?

Comment: @Biscuits: I know that can do because I'll assign "One command for One trancation", However I wanna the whole loop as a whole transcation.

Comment: Don't you want many commands in one transaction?

Comment: @Biscuits: I want. So Can you reply to me with a simple same in the form of persudo code?